# How to run HTML validation with onClick JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, constraint-validation-api

I'm trying to implement HTML validation in my project. Seems very helpful and easy for use. However this validation will work only if input type is set to `submit`. That part is causing problem for me. I have multiple forms and I use same `name` attribute on all Submit buttons. So my function looks like this:

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Info</legend>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_lname" id="frmst_lname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_fname" id="frmst_fname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." required/>
        </div>
        //Same button I have on the other forms. Only ID is different.
        <div class="formItem">
            <p align="center"><input type="button" name="frmSubmit" id="frmstSubmit" value="Submit"></p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="frmSubmit"]').on('click', function(){
    var frmID = $(this).closest('form').prop('id'); //take form ID
    var processVal = $(this).attr('data-process'); //which process will be executed Add or Edit
    //Here I would like to check form validation then process AJAX call
});
```

So far I couldn't get the HTML validation to work with `onClick` function. I tried to use `checkValidty()` but message never showed up for required fields on my form. I'm wondering if HTML is good fit for my project and how I can get validation to work with onClick function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want HTML validation to work, change button type to submit.

```
<input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="frmstSubmit" value="Submit">
```

If you want to do some custom validation add a onsubmit attribute.

```
<form method="POST" action="form-handler" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p>Input: <input type="text" size="32" name="inputfield">
<input type="submit"></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkForm(form)
  {
    if(!condition1) {
       alert("Error: error message");
       form.fieldname.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if(!condition2) {
       alert("Error: error message");
       form.fieldname.focus();
       return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
  }

</script>
```

see: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate/

If you want to use an AJAX call with HTML validation try using **e.preventDefault()** in a on submit function.

```
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {

            } else {

            }
        }
   });
})
```

or

```
$(document).on('submit','#myForm',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {

            } else {

            }
        }
   });
})
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shxqgnoL) to use one on change function for multiple forms and get id attribute.

Comment: I guess this won't work for me. It's designed more for single form. Like I mentioned above I have 4 different from's in my app. Function that I created will handle any of these forms. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe... $('#myform, #yourForm, #theirForm).on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); I don't know know, haven't tried.

Comment: how you would pass form ID? I don't get that part since your function is on submit?